# flutter get index value from .map()

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to retrieve the value of index from .map()

```
class ImageSliderScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<RecipeStepsModel>? recipeStepsList;
  ImageSliderScreen({required this.recipeStepsList});
  @override
  _ImageSliderScreenState createState() => _ImageSliderScreenState();

}
```

I have a list of `RecipeStepsModel` and I need to build a image carousel out of it:

```
      Container(
        child: CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(height: 400.0),
          items: widget.recipeStepsList!.map(
            (i) {
              return Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                    child: ImageCarouselCard(
                      recipeSteps: widget.recipeStepsList![i], //error
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ).toList(),
        ),
      ),
```

I'm getting this error: `The argument type 'RecipeStepsModel' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'`

What am I missing here? how can I get the index of my `recipeStepsList`?

Comment: use [mapIndexed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/ListExtensions/mapIndexed.html)

Comment: @MidhunMP nope in `ImageCarouselCard` RecipeStepsMOdel is declared

Comment: @FahimHoque i is not an integer. i is your `RecipeStepsModel`, so just write `recipeSteps: i`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `list.asMap().entries.map((e) {})`.

`e.key` will give the index
`e.vaule` will give the value at that index

```
    list.asMap().entries.map((e) {
      // e.key will give you the index
      print(e.key.toString());
      // e.value will give you the value at that index
      print(e.value.toString());
    });
```

Comment: there is no need for such workarounds as you have an extension method [mapIndexed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/ListExtensions/mapIndexed.html) which gives you both index and a corresponding list value

Comment: `e.value.toString()` prints `Instance of <'ClassName'>
`

Comment: For anyone who wants to use mapIndexed and your IDE doesn't want to auto import the required package because it's useless... This is the required import: import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) of `map` method. Your understanding of the method is wrong. The `i` that you are wrongly assuming to be the index is not the index, but the item itself from the list. So you need to change to this.

```
Container(
        child: CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(height: 400.0),
          items: widget.recipeStepsList!.map(
            (item) {
              return Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                    child: ImageCarouselCard(
                      recipeSteps: item,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ).toList(),
        ),
      ),
```